# How to add woocommerce classname to top sell product

Tags: post, woocommerce, classname

How can I add a classname of "topseller" to the top sell products on woocommerce?

Is there a function that checks whether product is top sell?

Comment: Can you provide more of an example? An online page where you're trying to do this? On pages where the items are sorted by popularity, you could apply this CSS to the top (first) item: `first-child` (see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp )

Comment: Sorry no online page I have. In woocommerce as you know, when a product is buyed by someone, this product's meta key (total_sales) incremented one value. I want to add a class to the products which are have biggest value of total_sales (this products are the top sell products).

Comment: Thank you Pat Gilmour I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did. Here is the solution;
first I generated a query which gets 10 products that have biggest total_sales

```
$query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm ON ( pm.post_id = p.ID AND pm.meta_key='total_sales' )
         WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
         AND p.post_status = 'publish'
         ORDER BY pm.meta_value+0 DESC
         LIMIT 10";

         $topselled_ids = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query,OBJECT ));
         //print_r ($topselled_ids );
         foreach  ($topselled_ids as  $one_topselled_id)
         $topselled[] =  $one_topselled_id->ID;
```

Then I checked if id of current product is in array (in the content-product.php) .

```
if ( in_array($post->ID, $topselled) )
$classes[] = "top_selled";
```